# Magento 2 add shipping cost in product collection

Tags: magento2, shipping-rates

I need to calculate shipping cost for each products so I used this code:

```
<?php

namespace Vebdor\Module\Model;

class ShippingCost
{
    protected $converter;
    
    protected $totalsCollector;

    protected $dataProcessor;

    protected $quote;

    protected $item;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter $converter,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector $totalsCollector,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
   ) {
        $this->converter = $converter;
        $this->totalsCollector = $totalsCollector;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->item = $item;
 
   }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function estimateByProductAndAddress($product, $countryId, $currency)
    {
        $this->item->setProduct($product);
        $this->item->setQty(1);

        $this->quote->addItem($this->item);

        $shippingAddress = $this->quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCountryId($countryId);
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);

        $this->totalsCollector->collectAddressTotals($this->quote, $shippingAddress);
        $shippingRates = $shippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
        
        $minPrice = NULL;
        foreach ($shippingRates as $carrierRates) {
            foreach ($carrierRates as $rate) {
                $price = round($this->converter->modelToDataObject($rate,$currency)->getAmount(),2);
                if(!$minPrice){
                    $minPrice = $price;
                } elseif ($minPrice > $price){
                    $minPrice = $price;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $minPrice;
    }
}
```

It works fine but after a while the foreach loop get slower and slower.

It will take 0.05 sec at the begining than up to 2/3 seconds.

Any suggestion is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by use a clone of quote and items:

```
public function estimateByProductAndAddress($product, $countryId, $currency)
{
    $item = clone $this->item;
    $quote = clone $this->quote;
...
```